# XSLT - Add namespace to node XML

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xml-namespaces

I have a simply `XML`:

```
<RequestResponse>
    <RequestResult>
        <FinalResponse>
            <Message>Request inserted successfully.</Message>
            <Response>true</Response>
        </FinalResponse>
    </RequestResult>
</RequestResponse>
```

I use a `XSLT` to include **FinalResponse** into a `CDATA` (String):

```
<RequestResponse>    
    <RequestResult>
        <![CDATA[<FinalResponse>      
                <Message>Request inserted successfully.</Message>
                <Response>true</Response>   
        </FinalResponse>]]>
    </RequestResult>   
</RequestResponse>
```

Then I use another `XSLT` more to convert the `XML` to `SOAP` with the namespace I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <RequestResponse>
            <RequestResult>
                <![CDATA[
                <FinalResponse>
                <Message>Request inserted successfully.</Message>
                <Response>true</Response>
                </FinalResponse>
                ]]>
            </RequestResult>
        </RequestResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to add this tag/namespace: `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` to the `RequestResponse` node, but **only** that node like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <RequestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <RequestResult>
                <![CDATA[
                <FinalResponse>
                <Message>Request inserted successfully.</Message>
                <Response>true</Response>
                </FinalResponse>
                ]]>
            </RequestResult>
        </RequestResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

How can I add that element only to that node?

Comment: You misunderstand how namespaces work. In your output, the `RequestResult` element inherits the default namespace declared for its parent `RequestResponse` element. You must place both elements in the same namespace, not only the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT stylesheet (http://xsltransform.net/bwdws2)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="RequestResult" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RequestResponse | RequestResponse//*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>            
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

transforms

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <RequestResponse>
            <RequestResult>
                <![CDATA[
                <FinalResponse>
                <Message>Request inserted successfully.</Message>
                <Response>true</Response>
                </FinalResponse>
                ]]>
            </RequestResult>
        </RequestResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

into

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <RequestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <RequestResult><![CDATA[

                <FinalResponse>
                <Message>Request inserted successfully.</Message>
                <Response>true</Response>
                </FinalResponse>

            ]]></RequestResult>
        </RequestResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I tries with your xsl transformation, but it doesn't add the CDATA. Please, read my answer below

Comment: I finally got it, changing the order of transformation. Thank you very much